# what is poweshell script to create app service plan for P1mv3

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

we are trying to create an Azure app service plan using Power shell script with pricing tier Premium p1mV3, but always creating as Premium P1 and the same issue happens while we creating Premium P0V3

PS script -

```
New-AzAppServicePlan -Name "app-service-plan-name" -ResourceGroupName "rg-name" -Location "East US" -Tier P1mv3 -WorkerSize Small
```

Note= We could able to create an app service plan with Premium v3 P1mv3 manually from the Azure portal in the new RG.

Please help on creating an exact script to create Premium P1mv3 and Premium P0V3 using Powershell

Actual result: actual.img

Expected  Result: expected1.img, expected2.img[expected1][actual][expected2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZjCP.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5hFi.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxFDo.png)

haven't created as expected as mentioned above in the description

Comment: Try with the command `New-AzAppServicePlan -Name "planname" -ResourceGroupName "rgname" -Location "East US" -Tier "Premium1v3" -WorkerSize Small`. [Image](https://i.imgur.com/P8e0Dzq.png), [Image](https://i.imgur.com/IbgqfJm.png)

Comment: hi @PravallikaKV i need price tier of  "p1mv3" or "p0v3" not as "p1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with the p1mv3 pricing plan that was identified using a powershell command, as confirmed in this [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1261222/p1mv3-not-recognized-as-a-premium-app-service-plan). Alternative approaches are to use either `Az CLI` or [`RestAPI`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/app-service-plans/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP).

Using **`az appservice plan create`**  CLI command:-

```bash
az appservice plan create --resource-group <resourcegroupname> --name newcliplan --sku P1mV3
```

**Note:** You can create an app service plan with different `sku` options as well. For P0V3, it will look like`--sku P0V3`.

[image]

[image]

**`New-AzAppServicePlan`** PowerShell command:-

*I was able to set up the other* `sku` *tier options* (for eg: P1V3) *using PowerShell.*

```
New-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroup> -Name <planname> -Location westus -Tier "PremiumV3"
```

[image]

[image]